# css js files deleted from ir attachments in Odoo V13

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I have mistakenly deleted the css,js files in ir_attachment model where res_model is "ir.ui.view".

Now when i load the server i see the below traceback error and complete UI styling gone.

```
Error:    
Traceback:
exception@http://172.16.250.21:8069/web/content/1000000030-e5f254f/web.assets_common.js:3692:7
_render@http://172.16.250.21:8069/web/content/1000000030-e5f254f/web.assets_common.js:3737:103
render@http://172.16.250.21:8069/web/content/1000000030-e5f254f/web.assets_common.js:3733:151
renderElement@http://172.16.250.21:8069/web/content/1000000030-e5f254f/web.assets_common.js:4090:1137
_widgetRenderAndInsert/<@http://172.16.250.21:8069/web/content/1000000030-e5f254f/web.assets_common.js:4100:6
```

Here's the list of files

```
'web_editor.assets_wysiwyg.css'
'web_editor.assets_wysiwyg.js'
'web.assets_frontend_minimal_js.js'
'web.assets_common_lazy.js'
'web.assets_frontend_lazy.js'
'web.report_assets_pdf.css'
'web.assets_common.css'
'web.report_assets_common.css'
'web.report_assets_common.css'
'web.assets_frontend.css'
'web.assets_common_minimal_js.js'
'web.assets_common.js'
'web.report_assets_common.js'
'web.report_assets_common.js'
```

I have added these manually but i couldnt see the issue fixed as the path url is linked with id
for eg: `/web/content/560-03d15b3/web_editor.assets_wysiwyg.css` where 560 is the id.

I just want to regenerate these records to make it work like before i delete them.
or is there any possibility of recover the deleted data of postgres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all you just need is to upgrade the `base` module, which would restore all qweb, js files

Comment: This also works when you restore a remote DB that has very different paths in `ir_attachment` as your local files. In this case, my reports were working but missed any styling. Reinstalling `base` fixed it!